# Why does USB errors with my mobile phone stop the computer from interacting with services?

Tags: arch-linux, usb

I set my Android phone to use "Mass storage" as the connection mode (In *Settings* → *Storage* → context menu item *USB computer connection*) to easily be able to browse the files. Then I plugged in the USB cable to my computer while on the login screen. I was able to log in, but after a while I got the following message:

[image: Connection failure - Connection activation failed - (1) Creating object for path '/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/4' failed in libnm-glib]

I tried `sudo systemctl stop NetworkManager`, but that hung. So I shut down the only GUI application which was running (Firefox), and tried to [reboot](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/master/.config/awesome/rc.lua#L138) the computer. That seemed to kill Awesome, because the screen went black, but it didn't reboot. I then tried `sudo reboot` on VT1, `sudo shutdown now` on VT2, and in the end just had to do a hard reboot.

After restarting the boot messages spewed out the following message repeatedly until I unplugged the phone:

```
hub 4-3:1.0: hub_port_status failed (err = -71)
```

Now, the question is not why the Android device misbehaved, but rather **why this was allowed to completely disrupt other system functionality.**

Comment: That's about the same thing as asking why Windows has BSODs. Bugs in kernel code can be fatal. News at 11.

Comment: You're saying this is a kernel bug? Wonder if it's possible to report it without reading 200 pages of documentation first...